# ASP .Net MVC site.master HTML.ActionLink new menu item set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink, html.actionlink

Just started MVC 2.0. There are built in views. In home there are two view. **Index.aspx** and **about.aspx**.
I am creating a new folder in Views named **customer** and create a new page "**Customer.aspx**" with some text to show. Menu item is created but not going into the page.

Here what i am trying.

```
<div id="menucontainer">

            <ul id="menu">              
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Customer", "CustomerDataAdd", "Customer")%></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

is the code alright?

The Error is :

---

### **Server Error in '/' Application.**

**The resource cannot be found.** 
**Description**: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

**Requested URL:** /Customer/CustomerDataAdd

---

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new `Controller` class called `Customer` with a method called `CustomerDataAdd` that will return the newly created `CustomerDataAdd` view.

```
public class Customer : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CustomerDataAdd()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hovercrafty. is it obvious For each view i creat2?

Comment: @decoyer - Yes, you'll need to create a controller method and view for each page of your site.  The controller class name (Customer in this example) and method (action) will make up the URLs of the pages.  So your example URL would be http://www.yoursite.com/Customer/CustomerDataAdd

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have `CustomerDataAdd` action in your `Customer` controller? There is nothing wrong in your HTML code.

```
public class Customer : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CustomerDataAdd()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it obvious For each view i create?